# VBA sort error. Code only works as separate module

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am trying to sort data by the values in the 3rd column. I have a 2 row header, and the code below by itself as a module works perfectly. When I copy and paste the code into another module, I get the '1004 error: The sort reference is not valid. Make sure it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.'

Why does the code only work by itself?

Code:

```
Sub sort()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 200
Set myRange = Sheets("Final").Range("A2", "S" & i)
myRange.sort Key1:=Range("C2"), order1:=xlAscending, _
                Header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlSortColumns
End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't fully qualifying your references. Try `Workbooks("yourworkbookname").Sheets("Final").Range("A2", "S" & i)` and `Key1:=Workbooks("yourworkbookname").Sheets("Final").Range("C2")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Range` argument for `Key1` isn't qualified fully. An unqualified range always refers to the *Active* worksheet, and if the active sheet is not the same as `Sheets("Final")`, then the error will be expected!

This should fix it:

```
Sub sort()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 200
    With Sheets("Final")
        Set myRange = .Range("A2", "S" & i)
        myRange.sort Key1:=.Range("C2"), order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlSortColumns
    End With

End Sub
```